# If $f, g : [a,b] \to\mathbb{R}$ are integrable then the following functions are also integrable...

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, maxima-minima

If $f, g : [a,b] \to\mathbb{R}$ are integrable then the following functions are also integrable
$$h : [a, b] \to\mathbb{R} \text{ with }   h(x) = \max\{f(x), g(x)\}.$$
$$T: [a, b] \to\mathbb{R} \text{ with } T(x) = \min\{f(x), g(x)\}.$$

For h:

It is worth that $$\max(a,b)=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$$

so

$$\max\{(x), g(x)\} = \frac{f(x) + g(x) + \mid f(x) - g(x)\mid}{2}$$

hence $\max\{f(x), g(x)\}$ is integrable because the absolute value is integrable.

For T:

It is worth that $$\min(a,b)=\frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$$

so

$$\min\{(x), g(x)\} = \frac{f(x) + g(x) - \mid f(x) - g(x)\mid}{2}$$

hence $\min\{f(x), g(x)\}$ is integrable because the absolute value is integrable.

Is my attempt correct/complete? It looks like a bit simple, but I can't think anything else to add. I appreciate in advance any assistance.

Comment: Yes, you can use this expression of $\max$ and $\min$ to good effect here. When you know the used results you are done.